# How can i display a static Block in Product Description in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can i display a static Block in Product Description in Magento 2?

I can display on cms Page or in phtml on Pruduct Description in Backend this not Works.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

does the block need to be "inbetween" your description elements or is it pre-/appended to the text content? In the 2nd case, a workaround could be extending your description. The easiest way to do that is to extend `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/description.phtml` in your theme. You could even build in some logic when to display the additional info and when to hide it.

If you need a more dynamic solution, you could use a custom text attribute and display it after the description output. In case this attribute would be empty, only the description is shown.